# Computing Potential Functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Find a function for which $\nabla f$ = $\vec{F}$, where $\vec{F} = \langle P,Q\rangle  = \langle \frac{x}{{\sqrt{x^2 + 7y^2}}}+6x^2y + 1, 2x^3 + \frac{7y}{\sqrt{x^2 + 7y^2}} \rangle$.

So, I verified that $Q_x - P_y = 0$. Thus, the function is conservative. However, I have no idea how to find the potential function. Can someone PLEASE walk me through it?

Comment: And be careful:   Your domain is not simply connected so you cannot conclude it's conservative from the curl vanishing.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

First note that you  have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+7y^2}} + 6x^2y+1$$

Treat $y$ as a constant when you integrate with respect to $x$.

So $$f(x,y) = \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+7y^2}} + 6x^2y+1 \, dx + g(y)$$

To solve for $g(y)$, differentiate the expression with respect to $y$ that you obtain above and compare with

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2x^3+ \frac{7y}{\sqrt{x^2+7y^2}}$$

Comment: So this verifies that they are conservative, sure, but how do I find the function f?

Comment: The second equation in my post, evaluate that integral.